# need total instructions for installing railink rt3290 in 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10

I need an help in installing this rt3290 drivers on Ubuntu 13.10. as I am an beginner in Ubuntu terminal I need instructions so that I can follow. my system is hp pavilion g6-2312ax.
even I need to install amd catalyst drivers in Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: On my 13.10 system, the 3290 device is covered by the driver rt2800pci which is installed by default. Is it not working for you as expected?

Comment: yes it is not working.. even I need driver installation of amd catalyst drivers as it has two graphic cards ( cross fire)

Comment: and please I need it need instructions as soon as possible

Comment: If you need to ask about graphics drivers, I suggest you start a new question referencing that; this question references wireless and I will try to answer it if I can.

Answer (score 0):

The driver for the Ralink 3290 device is included in Ubuntu 13.10 by default. If it is not working for you as expected, there is something else wrong. Let's troubleshoot. Is the switch or key combination set to enable wireless? Check from the terminal:

```
rfkill list all
```

Is the module rt2800pci loading on boot?

```
lsmod | grep rt2
```

Is a wireless interface, ideally wlan0 created?

```
iwconfig
```

Does it scan and see networks?

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Are there any informative clues in the message logs?

```
dmesg | grep -e rt2 -e wlan
```

When you click the Network Manager icon, do you see networks? What happens when you click yours and try to connect?

Please show us the logs here:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e rt2 -e etwork | tail -n20
```

Post it here and give us the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: it tries to connect but it disconnects after some min

Comment: i have been pasted the logs in ubuntu pastebin in rt3290

Comment: You didn't post the link to your paste.